# Get a file's extension with C

Tags: c, string, text-files

I'm trying to write a function in C to get a file's extension . So here's my code

```
char *getFileNameExtension(char *filename){
    char *ext = memchr(filename, '.',strlen(filename));
    return ext;
}
```

It works fine . But when I'm trying to check for a specific file type , like text files(.txt) I use this code

```
if (getFileNameExtension(filename)==".txt"){
   printf("%s\n",filename);
}
```

But it doesn't works . I tried to print the two strings as integers and as strings too

```
printf("%s %s",".txt",getFileNameExtension(txtFile));
printf("%d %d",".txt",getFileNameExtension(txtFile));
```

The first output is ok and I get : `.txt .txt` , but when I print them as integers(the ascii code I guess) I get this result : `27918619 4196714` . Also , every time the code is executed the int value of the first string is changed(due to different memory location I guess) . Could anyone help ?

Comment: What if the filename have multiple "extensions"? Use e.g. [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strrchr) to get the *last* dot.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Or not? I often use `.tar.gz` files...

Comment: By the way you have undefined behavior in your `printf` calls, you try to print two strings (or integers) but you only have one argument. Also, if you want to print a pointer you should use the format `"%p"`. Printing as an `int` will give wrong result on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Indeed, the concept of "the extension" is problematic. Neither the first dot nor the last dot is the "right" answer in cases like `package-a.b.c.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare strings like that, that way you're using is pointer comparison...

This is the correct version:

`if (strcmp(getFileNameExtension(filename), ".txt") == 0)`

I would suggest reading more on C strings.

Also, a highlight for googlers:

`What if the filename have multiple "extensions"? Use e.g. strrchr to get the last dot. –  Joachim Pileborg`

Comment: Ok, thanks! And what if I want to pass the string in another variable?

Comment: `char extension = getFileNameExtension(filename)` then `strcmp(extension, ".txt") == 0` is that what you meant or?

Comment: No , I mean to convert the pointer into string and pass this string only into another char type variable

Comment: Well, strings are `char` pointers in C, however, if you want to pass a string to another, you can use `strcpy` or `sprintf`

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two pointers, not two strings. Instead of

```
getFileNameExtension(filename)==".txt"
```

You should check:

```
!strcmp(getFileNameExtension(filename), ".txt")
```

Also, you may want to use `memrchr` or `strrchr`, so filenames with (a) period(s) return the last part as an extension.

Comment: That was useful too , I'll try it ..Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you may prefer to *not* use `memrchr` (in combination with `strlen`), since `strrchr` does that already correctly.